# Spotify Web API Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, spotify

I am making a small side-project to get better with using website APIs and jQuery.  Unfortunately I am not doing that well.  What I am trying to do is use the Spotify Web API to get 3 of my playlists and just put them on a web page.

I currently have:

```
var accessToken = "{my-token}";
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{my-username}/playlists?limit=3&offset=0',
    type: 'GET',
    headers {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this.  After I figure it out I am going to create a quick how-to for any future people that are not-so-familiar with using jQuery to access Web APIs

Comment: Did you first acquire an access token following [these steps](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/)?

Comment: @PatrickQ I may have acquired my access token wrong now that I think about it. I just went to the Web Console and generated one that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotify's Web API return HTTP status code 401 Unauthorized ([Error code documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/#response-status-codes)) when the access token has expired or when the access token is invalid. Printing out the error response's body would give you further clues about why the API returned the 401.

Access token expire in an hour, but can be refreshed depending on the way you retrieved it. You can read more about the different ways of retrieving access tokens in the [Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/), or check out the [web-api-auth-examples](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples) project on Github.

Comment: After giving it a good read through, I may have been acquiring the access token wrong. I'm not that good with these types of things so sorry if my following question is basic: Out of the three git hub examples, is there one where I don't need the user to login? I just  want to be able to supply my client id/secret key and then access my playlist instead of having the user login with their spotify account. Is something like that a possibility?

Comment: Yes, the Client Credentials flow allow you to send a request without use authentication. An important difference here is that you cannot make any changes on behalf of a user using access tokens acquired this way, since no user has given your application permission to do so. Also note that the Client Credentials flow is suited for server to server communication since you need to include your client_secret in the request. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah that helps very much thanks! Pretty much as a side project for my office, I am making an office jukebox that will be hosted internally here. Then the user just goes to the site location and can vote for the next song. Then we just get that song from the playlist that we have. Now I just need to get better with Node.js :p

Comment: Sounds like a fun project. Good luck!